# Can't get initialValues to set for Redux-Form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I've spent the greater part of four days struggling with this. I have a form that is used to update some date.  My requirement is simply to fetch data from a remote source, and have the initialValues in the form set based on the data received. The user then makes changes and submit. The data is successfully fetched from the remote source but I can't get the data to populate the form fields.

Setting initialValues in the connect function results in each being undefined. Note: I put the initial value. Note: if i don't include the data retrieved from store outside of the initialValue, it won't work. This is totally confusing to me.  I've literally read hundreds of posts, but nothing has worked.

```
  import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
  import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { getDataResource } from '../../../actions'
  import {  Form, Input, Button, Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";


  const theSource = [
    { text:"Internal",value: 1 },
    { text:"External",value: 2 }
  ]


  const dataState =[  
    {text:"dormant",value: 3 },
    {text:"low",value: 1 },
    {text:"viral",value: 2 }

  ]
  const theFormat = [
    {text:"SQL",value: 1},
    {text:"JSON",value: 2}
  ]


  class UpdateData extends Component {

    constructor( props ) {
      super( props );

      this.state={

      }

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.dispatch(getDataResource(this.props.theId));
    }

    renderSelect = (field) => (    
      <Form.Select
        label={field.label}
        name={field.input.name}
        onChange={(e, { value }) => field.input.onChange(value)}
        options={field.options}
        placeholder={field.placeholder}
        value={field.input.value}
      />
    );

    renderTextArea = field => (
      <Form.TextArea
        {...field.input}
        label={field.label}
        placeholder={field.placeholder}
      />
    );

    render(){

      return (
        <Fragment>
          <Form className="form ui" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h4>Information</h4>

                <Field
                    size="small"
                    component={Form.Input}
                    name="dname"
                />

                <Field
                    size="small"
                    component={Form.Input}
                    name="location"
                    placeholder={`Reference: ${this.props.location}`}
                />

                <Field
                    component={this.renderTextArea}
                    size="small"
                    name="description"
                    placeholder="Important details about resource"
                /> 
                <h4>Critical details about the data  </h4>
                <Field
                    size="small"
                    component={this.renderSelect}
                    name="source"
                    options={theSource}
                />
                <Field
                    size="small"
                    component={this.renderSelect}
                    name="state"
                    options={dataState}
                    placeholder={`Level of data tidiness is: ${state}`}
                />
                <Field
                    size="small"
                    component={this.renderSelect}
                    name="format"
                    options={theFormat}
                />

            <Button primary type='submit'>Add Resource</Button> 
          </Form>
        </Fragment>

      )


    }


  }


  UpdateData = reduxForm({
     form: 'UpdateFormReactWidgets'
  })(UpdateData)


  export default connect((state) => ({
    initialValues: {
      dname: state.dataDetailResource.name,
      description: state.dataDetailResource.description,
      location: state.dataDetailResource.location,
      source: state.dataDetailResource.source,
      state: state.dataDetailResource.state,
      format: state.dataDetailResource.format
    },
    enableReinitialize: true
    /*,
      dname: state.dataDetailResource.name,
      description: state.dataDetailResource.description,
      location: state.dataDetailResource.location,
      source: state.dataDetailResource.source,
      state: state.dataDetailResource.state,
      format: state.dataDetailResource.format*/
  }))(UpdateData);
```

I simply need the values retrieved to show in the form fields as the initial values.

Comment: What does `getDataResource()` do?

Comment: getDataResource() is the action call that pulls the original data from the server. So it gets the data that populated the dname, location, description etc. fields.

Comment: Does putting `enableReinitialize: true` as part of the `reduxForm` config properties work? E.g.: `UpdateData = reduxForm({ form: 'UpdateFormReactWidgets', enableReinitialize: true })(UpdateData);
`